# How to implement the transfer of parameters to the method using jquery(ajax) and then download the file created in the method to the computer

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

On the view page, I added a datetimepicker taken from [daterangepicker](https://www.daterangepicker.com/)
It passes the start and end date parameters to the ajax script. After that, the script passes this data to a method that generates an Excel document with data for a selected period of time. I would like this file created in the method to be downloaded to my computer, but using ajax does not allow me to do this.

My view code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="main">
            <div class="container">         
                <div class="marga">             
                <p>
                       <label>Period:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="daterange" value="03/12/2024 - 01/15/2024"/>
                        <script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/datepicker/moment.min.js"></script>
                        <script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/datepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
                        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/css/daterangepicker.css" />
                   </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker();
            $('input[name="daterange"]').on('apply.daterangepicker', function (ev, picker) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("CreateDocument", "Docs")',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { "dateStart": picker.startDate.format('DD-MM-YYYY'), "dateEnd": picker.endDate.format('DD-MM-YYYY') },
                dataType: "json"
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I also tried to create a link using `window.location`, but this led to the fact that even with a correctly created link, the browser displayed a message saying that the page was not found

My method code:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateDocument(DateOnly dateStart, DateOnly dateEnd)
{
    using (VapeshopContext db = new VapeshopContext())
    {
        ExcelDataModel excelData = new ExcelDataModel
        {
            totalSales = db.Transactions.Where(ts => (ts.Date >= dateStart) && (ts.Date <= dateEnd) && (ts.IsViewed == true) && (ts.TransactionStatusId == 2)).Count(),              
            totalSum = (float)db.Transactions.Where(ts => (ts.Date >= dateStart) && (ts.Date <= dateEnd) && (ts.IsViewed == true) && (ts.TransactionStatusId == 2)).Sum(ts => ts.Sum),
            productRest = db.ProductCounts.Sum(pc => pc.Count),
            productReceipt = db.ReplenishmentProducts.Where(rp=>(rp.Date >= dateStart) && (rp.Date <= dateEnd)).Sum(rp=>rp.Quantity),
            
            receiptProducts = from p in db.ReplenishmentProducts.Include(rp=>rp.Product).Include(rp=>rp.Product.ProductCounts)/*.Where(rp=>(rp.Date >= dateStart) && (rp.Date <= dateEnd))*/
                           select new receiptProduct()
                           {
                               productName = p.Product.Title,
                               cost = (float)p.Product.Cost,
                               quantity = p.Quantity,
                               dateReceipt = p.Date
                           },
            
            restProducts = from pr in db.ProductCounts.Include(p => p.Product).Where(pc => pc.Count > 0)
                           select new restProduct()
                           {
                               productName = pr.Product.Title,
                               remains = pr.Count,
                               cost = (float)pr.Product.Cost
                           }
        };
 
        
        var Excel = new ExcelGenerator()
            .Generate(excelData);
        

       return File(Excel, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", $"Report {dateEnd}.xlsx");
    }           
}
```

Comment: You can save excel file in server side(i mean after generate excel file , save it in server side in a specific route) and return file name for client. Then in client side use this : 

document.location = "../../TextFiles/" + data.d;